# boost::shared_ptr reference counting does is solve raw pointer of tr1::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

Does `boost::shared_ptr` solve raw pointer problem?

```
Base* p = new Base();

shared_ptr <Base> sp(p);
shared_ptr <Base> sq(p);
```

Both `shared_ptr`s have ref count as 1 so raw pointer is issue.

Does `boost::shared_ptr` also have this problem?

I heard there is no issue with `boost::shared_ptr` then how it solved it?

Comment: Smart pointers introduce reference counting and care of the proper deletion of the contained pointee, as soon there are no more references.

Answer (score 2):

No, `boost::shared_ptr` doesn't solve this problem.

The problem is in your code, so you need to solve it yourself.

The best solution is to ensure you **always** initialize a smart pointer **immediately** when you create an object with `new`:

```
shared_ptr <Base> sp(new Base());
```

Now there is no raw pointer, so no problem.

Even better:

```
shared_ptr<Base> sp = make_shared<Base>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You heard wrong.  This would definitely not work with boost or std `shared_ptr`.

What is provided is a shared_from_this construct.  You inherit from a base class that does some magic to find the shared_ptr reference (and set it when you first adopt the pointer).  Then you can get a new shared from a raw pointer:

```
p->shared_from_this();
```

If you call that though the thing had darn well have been adopted by a shared pointer already or it will do really horrible things and touch you in all the embarrassing places.  It pays well to enforce it through a `create` function that has to be called instead of the constructor.  This then makes sure nobody creates one that's not in a `shared_ptr` and calls that function.

I try really hard to avoid having to use this construct.  If you're so darn sure your type has to be in a shared ownership construct then just make it use intrusive pointers.  An intrusive pointer that had trouble with raw pointers would be a pretty silly thing...I don't know of one that does.  Your code would work with them.